# Forma correta de fazer um grande inner join

Tags: mysql, join

Bom dia, pessoal.
Sou iniciante no php e estou desenvolvendo um programa para controle de caixas de arquivo.
Eu tenho um banco de dados no qual a tabela "caixa" é a principal, ela tem várias referências para outras tabelas. Segue:

```
<br>CREATE TABLE `caixa` (<br>
`nro_caixa` int(6) NOT NULL,<br>
`auditor` varchar(150) NOT NULL,<br>
`id_cliente` int(5) NOT NULL,<br>
`observacao` text NOT NULL,<br>
`data_ini` date DEFAULT NULL,<br>
`data_fin` date DEFAULT NULL,<br>
`tipo_caixa` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,<br>
`data_cadastro` datetime NOT NULL,<br>
`data_descarte` datetime DEFAULT NULL,<br>
`obs_descarte` varchar(150) NOT NULL,<br>
`res_descarte` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,<br>
`id_departamento` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,<br>
`id_unidade` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,<br>
`id_tipo_doc` int(10) NOT NULL,<br>
`id_status` int(11) NOT NULL,<br>
`id_prateleira` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,<br>
`id_caixa` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,<br>
PRIMARY KEY (`id_caixa`),<br>
KEY `id_status` (`id_status`),<br>
KEY `id_prateleira` (`id_prateleira`),<br>
KEY `res_descarte` (`res_descarte`),<br>
KEY `id_unidade` (`id_unidade`),<br>
KEY `id_tipo_doc` (`id_tipo_doc`),<br>
KEY `id_departamento` (`id_departamento`),<br>
KEY `id_cliente` (`id_cliente`)<br>
)
ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=37259 ;
```

Eu preciso de uma forma de pegar informações de outras tabelas como nomes de tipos de documento, nome de unidade, nome de perfil, nome da prateleira e nome do departamento que são campos em outras tabelas.
O que tentei até agora:

```
SELECT <br>a.id_caixa,<br> a.nro_caixa,<br> a.auditor,<br> a.observacao,<br> a.data_ini,<br> a.data_fin,<br> a.tipo_caixa,<br> b.nome,<br> c.nome,<br> d.nome,<br> e.nome,<br> f.nome<br> 
FROM CAIXA AS a<br>
INNER JOIN clientes AS b<br>
INNER JOIN departamento AS c<br>
INNER JOIN tipo_doc AS d<br>
INNER JOIN unidade as e<br>
INNER JOIN perfil_doc as f<br>
WHERE a.nro_caixa = $numero
```

O que acontece é que o banco fica procurando infinitamente. Quando limitei a query para 20 resultados percebi que ele está pegando alguns valores repetidos e não está pegando outros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que esteja faltando a condição de ligação `ON` para os `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT
    a.id_caixa,
    a.nro_caixa,
    a.auditor,
    a.observacao,
    a.data_ini,
    a.data_fin,
    a.tipo_caixa,
    b.nome,
    c.nome,
    d.nome,
    e.nome
FROM
    CAIXA AS a
    INNER JOIN clientes AS b        ON b.id_cliente = a.id_cliente
    INNER JOIN departamento AS c    ON c.id_departamento  = a.id_departamento 
    INNER JOIN tipo_doc AS d        ON d.id_tipo_doc = a.id_tipo_doc
    INNER JOIN unidade AS e         ON e.id_unidade = a.id_unidade
WHERE
    a.nro_caixa = $numero
```

E também parece estar faltando a `KEY` para a tabela Perfil.

Comment: Deu certo!!! Sua resposta também ajudou pra caramba a montar e entender a sql aqui.
Muito obrigado! :)

Comment: Na verdade a tabela perfil faz referência à tabela tipo_doc por isso ela não tem key na tabela caixa. Mas fiz a ligação usando esse modelo e funcionou certinho!

Answer (score 2):

Amigo, o que ocorre é que se você simplesmente adicionar o `INNER JOIN` **sem indicar as ligações entre as tabelas** você terá como resultado da consulta uma quantidade de registros igual a **multiplicação das linhas de todas as tabelas envolvidas**.

Por exemplo:

> tabela1: 50 registros
>
> tabela2: 5 registros

Com uma instrução `SELECT` assim:

```
SELECT *
  FROM tabela1
 INNER JOIN tabela2
```

Você teria um retorno de **250 registros**, pois para **cada linha da tabela1** a `SELECT` **retorna 5 linhas**, **uma para cada linha da tabela2**.

Você indica a ligação entre as tabelas através do uso das **chaves estrangeiras (*FK - Foreign Key*)**.

As **chaves estrangeiras** de sua tabela são os **campos que fazem referências a outras tabelas**, normalmente são as **chaves primárias das outras tabelas**.

Continuando o exemplo, o correto então seria a seguinte `SELECT`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM tabela1
 INNER JOIN tabela2 ON tabela1.chave_estrangeira = tabela2.chave_primaria
```

O uso do `ON` no `INNER JOIN` é que indica a ligação entre as tabelas e limita o resultado da `SELECT`.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Deu certo!!! era isso mesmo!
Muito obrigado! :)

Comment: Que bom amigo. Se a solução resolveu seu problema não esqueça de sinalizar. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Eu aceitei a do V. Bevilaqua por estar mais explicadinha. Mas essa me ajudou bastante também! Valeu!

Comment: Sem problemas amigo!