# Join repete registros?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Eu tenho tabelas no banco de dados que se relacionam. A (t.a) tem quatro linhas que se relacionam com as outras quatro linhas da (t.b) A consulta realiza-se por meio de um (user.id) que existe nas duas tabelas.

O problema acontece no retorno da consulta que repete mais 12 linhas ? Como posso tratar esse erro ? Abaixo segue o code e link:

```
public function planstypes_head($elev_opename_id) {
   $this->db->select('*');
   $this->db->from('elev_plans_types');
   $this->db->join('elev_share_plans', 'elev_share_plans.elev_opename_id = elev_plans_types.elev_opename_id' , 'left');
   $this->db->where('elev_plans_types.elev_opename_id', $elev_opename_id);
   $query = $this->db->get();
   return $query->result(); 
}
```

Link: http://elevsaude.webstrucs.com/tabelas/elevsaude/operadora/1

Comment: Dependendo da consulta o join retornar registros 'duplicados', tem algum motivo especial para usar o `left join`?

Comment: Relacionado: [Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6441/91)

Comment: Organiza os dados da tabela b com a. Sem a listagem fica sem sincronização: dados.a, dados.a, dados.a, dados.a.

Comment: Troca o `left` por `inner` veja se apresenta o resultado esperado.

Comment: somente lista um registro.

Comment: preciso que liste o restante relacionado.

Comment: Adicione as estruturas de suas tabelas. Quantos registros tem em cada uma? Qual o retorno correto do query? Isso pode ser útil: [Forma correta de fazer um grande inner join](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/134341/forma-correta-de-fazer-um-grande-inner-join)

Answer (score 2):

Boa tarde.
Creio que se alterar a linha

```
$this->db->select('*');
```

Para

```
$this->db->select('elev_plans_types.*');
```

Ficara certo.
Acontece que se tu colocar somente o '*', tu tá mandando selecionar os dados da tabela `elev_plans_types` e da tabela `elev_share_plans`.
Espero ter ajudado.

Oss

Comment: Nesse caso sim, mas os dados que precisam ser listados são como base no parâmetro.

Answer (score 1):

Você deve agrupar os registros pelo campo principal que você procura. Acredito que se fizer `$this->db->group_by("elev_plans_types.elev_opename_id");` funcione.

Comment: Tentei também, porém filtra somente uma linha relacionada. As três restantes somem ?

Comment: Qual o campo principal que você quer que apareça mesmo se alguns outros fiquem nulo? Geralmente é por esse que você terá que agrupar

Comment: elev_plans_types e elev_share_plans.